# Unwrappable float is clearing in IE, but renders with scrollbars in all other browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

On one page on my site, I have a table in the right column that is too wide and rather than showing scrollbars, IE is wrapping it below the content in the left column. I can't find a fix for this because I don't know how to describe what's happening.

Here's the code I'm using to demonstrate the problem:

```
<style>
  #col1 { float: left; width:189px;  font-size:8pt;}
  #col3 { width: auto; margin: 0 0 0 191px; }
</style>             
<body>           
    <div id="col1">
            <div style="padding-top:30em;border:1px solid red">really tall</div>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">        
            <h1>title</h1>  
            <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here's how it renders in IE:
[image]

In all other browsers, the table of a's shows just under "title" and I get a horizontal scrollbar. This is what I'd expect, but for some reason, IE wants to clear the content in col1. I've tried applying widths, floats, etc, but I can't get IE to put the table under the title without clearing the col1 content.

I assume there's some IE hack for this, but what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `zoom:1` to the css of #col3, this will solve (it's related to haslayout issue)

http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/ZPztF/

p.s. It's a kind of magic (cit. Queen) =)

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout

Comment: Question for my own edification is setting the zoom here to force the "hasLayout" property to true or does it flip a different hidden setting in IE?

Comment: I tried that already and it has no effect in IE6. @antonlavey - it's only used to trigger hasLayout to true.

Comment: Confirmed that this works in IE7.  Thanks for the clarification meder

Comment: Nice. If IE6 doesn't matter, use this.

Comment: the first you said. Probably you will obtain the same result changing some other property e.g. (direction: ltr)

Comment: @jody: I just tried on jsfiddle on IE7, but without zoom:1 I can't see it right... weird

Comment: Yup, this fixes it! I knew there was some layout issue with IE. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @fcalderan - you're right - this only works in strict mode. In IE7 quirks mode, it doesn't fix the problem. I'm concerned if I turn on strict mode I could raise all sorts of other issues on my site.

Comment: Ack didn't test it in quirks mode )=

Comment: seriously, you had to start writing in your page with a strict doctype. this ensure less layout differences amongs browser

Comment: I agree with you, but I've been working on this site since 1999. It's commercial and with hundreds of pages. It's not so easy for me to switch.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set a width on `col3`? If not, try adjusting the border to be a css, not html border. Also try `border-collapse:collapse;` on the table. If you can set a width on col3, also use `overflow:hidden;`. You can also attempt to use `inline-block` on *both* instead of floats.

**EDIT**: Finally got my solution working in IE6. It requires source order changes, but content can be first now.

**EDIT #2**: My solution works in quirks IE6/IE7/IE8 and standards IE6/IE7/IE8 as well as Fx, Chrome.

http://work.arounds.org/sandbox/67/run

Comment: I can't set a width on col3 - it's a fluid layout and expands with the browser width. I tried your other suggestions with no luck.

Comment: +1 to make up for the downvote, its a perfectly reasonable answer

Comment: I down voted because overflow: hidden could result in content being unreachable if the content goes beyond the width of the containing div assuming that the containing div's width is constrained at some point.  Since that is most likely not the goal here I downvoted as it could have negative consequences that might not have been shown in the test case.

Comment: @antonlavey - overflow hidden sometimes fixes width rendering issues dealing with floats in IE, that's why I suggested it. I am of course aware of the  potential issues. Anyways, my fix works in every browser without overflow hidden.

Comment: @meder Offering up a fix that can cause content to become unreachable without warning that it could happen is why I down voted.  Wasn't debating the fix but rather the lack of warning that it can cause a different and arguably much more serious bug to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding overflow:auto; to the #col3 style?